# VBA: Read multiple textfiles and make a excel sheet for each one at the end of my current workbook

Tags: excel, vba, file

Hallo I new to VBA and currently working on a project where i have to read a lot of files (pick them with my mouse) and put the data that is demilated by space in exel sheet in my current workbook (but at the end of my worksheets because I already have sheets that has to stay in the beginning) I am using.

I found a code that almost does what I need but:

- This Code cant open all files because the file name has more than 30 letters in it.

textfile looks like this "name1_name2_name3_name4_name5_name6.txt" is it possible to search for a specific name for example name1,3,4 is enough to know which file it is. I am asking because 
I have to merge some files into one sheet if the name1 name2 fit together.

- it opens up a need workbook instead of putting the new sheets in my current workbook

the Code for example

```
Sub ReadText()
Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
Dim I As Integer

Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xTempWb As Workbook
Dim xDelimiter As String

Dim xScreen As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
xDelimiter = "|"
xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Error", , True)

'falls nichts ausgewählt abbrechen
If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Error"
    GoTo ExitHandler
End If
''''''''''''''''''''''''
'nächste Code Schritte
I = 1
Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
xTempWb.Close False
xWb.Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
  Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
  TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
  Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
  Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
  Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"

Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
    I = I + 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    With xWb
        xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        .Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
          Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
          TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
          ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
          Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
          Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
          Other:=True, OtherChar:=xDelimiter
    End With
Loop
''''''''''''''''''
'Falls keine File ausgewählt springt er hier her
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xTempWb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error"
    Resume ExitHandler
End sub
```

Is there someone who can help me solve this problem with this code? Or is there a easier way programm what I need

Comment: I would be very glad if someone knows a good website where i can learn vba on my own. I already worked with some tutorials but I am still not able to understand most of the codes that are out there and what some functions are doing.

Comment: What is  text's delimiter? Tab or "|" ?

Comment: My textfiles get delimiter by tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Sub ReadText()
    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xTempWb As Workbook
    Dim xDelimiter As String
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim vDB As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, Target As Range

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) '<~~ set sheet that you want.

    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", , "Error", , True)


    'falls nichts ausgewahlt abbrechen
    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , "Error"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'nachste Code Schritte

    For i = 1 To UBound(xFilesToOpen)

        Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(i), Format:=1)
        '@@ format number ;  1= tab, 2= comma,3=space, 4=semicolon ,5= none, 6= user delimiter
        'vDB = xTempWb.Sheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion '<~~ if there are empty rows or columns, this can not get data beyond that.
        vDB = xTempWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange '<~ get sheet's whole data
        Set Target = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Target.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB
        xTempWb.Close (0)
    Next i
    ''''''''''''''''''
    'Falls keine File ausgewahlt springt er hier her
ExitHandler:
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
        Set xWb = Nothing
        Set xTempWb = Nothing
        Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
        MsgBox Err.Description, , "Error"
        Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Dy.Lee. Thanks for your response. It helped a lot. I still have a problem understanding your code. When i open my files your codes does not copy the hole textfile. It stops after a vertical row is empty. Is there a way to read the hole document and not stop after a enter key in my textdocument? And is it possible to place the data from the textfile next to each other in the sheet i am placing it in  and not under each other?

Comment: @Fabian Linek,  vDB = xTempWb.Sheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion  to  vDB = xTempWb.Sheets(1).usedrange

Comment: Thank you very much that worked perfect! I would like to understand this on my own, is there a website you would recommend to learn this on my own? Lets say i want to improve your code and put the textdata next to each other in that excel sheet and not under each other?